# Node npm install seems to be installing a different version to github

Tags: node.js, github, npm

I can see the version of generator-webapp that I want in github but when I do an npm install, it seems to be giving me an older version.

I note that the version number in the packages.json hasn't been updated in the last few changes. I don't know if that is a factor.

Answer (score 0):

The version you install with npm must be published on npmjs.com
For example, last published [generator-webapp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-webapp) version is 0.5.1

If you want the last version from github
Use that `npm install git+https://isaacs@github.com/npm/npm.git` (with the repo you want of course)

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about npmjs.com. I thought the publication point was github. It seems to be the problem that version 0.5.1 has been updated several times without updating the version no.